# Unable to format the numeric data in GXT Grid Cell?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I want to format the numeric values like `1,23,456` and display the data in the Grid. I modified the Grid column renderer to return the string like I mentioned above. Below is the renderer code:

```
String value = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##,##0").format(123456d);
```

But am getting the value like following `123,456`. Could someone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: according to NumberFormat GWT doc http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html : ',' is a grouping pattern. Maybe you could try with ';'

Answer (score 1):

The method `format` only allows one grouping size:

```
protected void format(boolean isNegative, StringBuilder digits, int scale) {
...
    int currentGroupingSize = this.groupingSize;
...
```

So, when your format pattern is analized it takes the first grouping size.

For example, if we try

```
String value = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,###,#0").format(123456d);
```

we will get 12,34,56

Hope this helps.